# How to make an if-else control structure in 68k language?

Tags: assembly, if-statement, cpu, 16-bit, 68000

I'm writing a program for 68k processor in ASM.

And I need to make something like that

```
if (D0 > D1) {
   do_some_stuff();
   do_some_stuff();
   do_some_stuff();
   do_some_stuff();
} else {
   do_some_stuff();
   do_some_stuff();
   do_some_stuff();
   do_some_stuff();
}
```

But the problem is that it only allows me to either branch to some pointer or continue execution.

Like so:

```
CMP.L   D0,D1       ; compare
BNE AGAIN       ; move to a pointer
```

What is the easiest way to make such construction as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
if (D0>D1) {
    //do_some_stuff
} else {
    //do_some_other_stuff
}
```

Should be:

```
CMP.L   D0,D1       ; compare
BGT AGAIN  
//do_some_other_stuff
BR DONE
AGAIN:
//do_some_stuff
DONE:
```

Read more about [conditional branching](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/68000_Assembly#Conditional_tests)

Comment: Hm. Also some addition - it only compares D0==D1, is it possible to compare "D0 > D1" or "D0 < D1" directly somehow?

Comment: @NewProger `BGT` branches if greater than, see the link

Comment: Won't `BGT` Branch on `D1 >  D0` after `CMP D0, D1` in 68k?

Answer (score 1):

The control structure that is best suited for this scenario is `BGT`.

`BGT` (**Branch on greater than**) will branch when the second operand is greater than the first operand. This makes sense when you look at what is going on behind the scenes.

```
CMP.W D1,D0 ;Performs D0-D1, sets the CCR, discards the result
```

It sets the CCR (Condition Code Register) because the branch is taken only when **(N=1 and V=1 and Z=0)** or **(N=0 and V=0 and Z=0)**.

Now to transform:

```
if (D0 > D1) {
    //do_some_stuff
} else {
    //do_some_other_stuff
}
```

Into 68k assembly language:

```
     CMP.W   D1,D0       ;compare the contents of D0 and D1
     BGT     IF 
     // do_some_other_stuff
     BRA     EXIT
IF
     // do_some_stuff
EXIT ...
```